# Color of the evaluating cell brackets

Tags: evaluation, cells, stylesheet

What is the option to use in a stylesheet that controls the color of the brackets for cells in the evaluation queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAICT there's no setting to control that. Looking at [CellBracketOptions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellBracketOptions.html), there's only *two options* for controlling the colors of brackets:

1. `"Color"` - the cell's bracket color
2. `"HoverColor"` - the cell bracket's color on mouse-over

But unfortunately, no such option like `"EvaluationColor"` or `"QueuedColor"` seems to exist.

```
CellPrint[Cell["Example", "Text", CellBracketOptions -> {
        "Color" -> Blue, "HoverColor" -> Green, 
        "Thickness" -> 5, "Widths" -> {10, 10}}]
     ]
```

[image]

Perhaps a developer knows of an undocumented option or front-end setting?